# Json parsing issue in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I need to parse following json in vb.net. I'm using Json.net but do not know how to do it.

Problem occurs in  scan result contains scan detail that conaints anti virus name with some detail. but all the anti-virus is object not an array. So please any body tell me how to do it.

```
{"file_id":"aaa60a443e3a4426944da9e6fe8a3f3c","scan_results":{"scan_details":{"AegisLab":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Agnitum":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Ahnlab":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-24T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Antiy":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"AVG":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Avira":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"BitDefender":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"ByteHero":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"ClamWin":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"CYREN":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"DrWebGateway":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Emsisoft":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"ESET":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Filseclab":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Fortinet":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"F-prot":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"F-secure":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"GFI":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Hauri":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Ikarus":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Jiangmin":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"K7":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-20T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Kaspersky":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Lavasoft":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"McAfee-Gateway":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Microsoft":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"NANO":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"nProtect":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Preventon":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"QuickHeal":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Sophos":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"STOPzilla":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-21T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"SUPERAntiSpyware":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Symantec":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Tencent":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"TotalDefense":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"TrendMicro":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-21T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"TrendMicroHouseCall":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-21T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"VirIT":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-20T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"VirusBlokAda":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-20T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Xvirus":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-23T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Zillya!":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-22T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0},"Zoner":{"scan_result_i":0,"threat_found":"","def_time":"2015-02-18T00:00:00Z","scan_time":1.0}},"rescan_available":true,"data_id":"32fe182492834b6f88b1d95f6a14c886","scan_all_result_i":0,"start_time":"2015-02-23T13:10:55.549Z","total_time":1.0,"total_avs":43,"progress_percentage":100,"in_queue":0,"scan_all_result_a":"Clean"},"file_info":{"file_size":0,"upload_timestamp":"2015-02-23T00:40:41.029Z","md5":"D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E","sha1":"DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709","sha256":"E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855","file_type_category":"O","file_type_description":"empty","file_type_extension":"-","display_name":"C:\\testy.xml"},"data_id":"32fe182492834b6f88b1d95f6a14c886"}
```

Comment: How does the class you use to deserialize the json string into and the code you use to actually deserialize look like?

Comment: Sloth, I have not done any thing. Actually I have started working on vb.net for yesterday. So Need an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a class (or multiple) that can represent the data you want to deserialize.

Looking at the input string you provided, you need a class for `FileInfo`, `ScanDetail`, `ScanResults` and one for the root (let's call it `Scan`).

It's simply a matter of mapping the JSON keys to a class property (and a dictionary for `ScanDetail`, since you probably don't want a property for each of it).

So, your classes should look like this:

```
public class Scan
    public property file_id() as string
    public property scan_results() AS ScanResults 
    public property file_info() as FileInfo
    public property data_id() as string
End Class

public class ScanResults
    public property scan_details As Dictionary(Of string, ScanDetail)
    Public Property rescan_available() As Boolean
    Public Property data_id() As String
    Public Property scan_all_result_i() As Integer
    Public Property start_time() As String
    Public Property total_time() As Double
    Public Property total_avs() As Integer
    Public Property progress_percentage() As Integer
    Public Property in_queue() As Integer
    Public Property scan_all_result_a() As String
End Class

public class ScanDetail
    public property scan_result_i() As integer
    public property threat_found() as string
    public property def_time() as string
    public property scan_time() as string
End class

Public Class FileInfo
    Public Property file_size() As Integer
    Public Property upload_timestamp() As String
    Public Property md5() As String
    Public Property sha1() As String
    Public Property sha256() As String
    Public Property file_type_category() As String
    Public Property file_type_description() As String
    Public Property file_type_extension() As String
    Public Property display_name() As String
End Class
```

Now the deserializing is as easy as

```
Dim details = NewtonSoft.JSon.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Scan)(your_json_string)
```

---

To get all `threat_found` values, you can easily query the result:

```
Dim threats = details.scan_results.scan_details.Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.threat_found) _
                                               .Where(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)) _
                                               .ToList()
```

Comment: I need to get Virus Count on specific file. So from your code I think I'm unable to do it

Comment: @user1679960 There's no `Virus Count` in your JSON string.

Comment: @user1679960 It seems you're looking for `threat_found`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to deserialize that JSON string assuming  you have referenced Json.Net. What you get is a dynamic object with property names the same as the JSON property  names. If you were to create a Class with the correct properties you could also deserialize into that specific type and you would have the benefit of strong typing. Put a break point after this code and run with Debug. Look in the Locals window and you can inspect "theobj"'s properties.

```
    Dim obj As String = "{""file_id"":""aaa60a443e3a4426944da9e6fe8a3f3c"",""scan_results"":{""scan_details"":{""AegisLab"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Agnitum"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Ahnlab"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-24T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Antiy"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""AVG"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Avira"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""BitDefender"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""ByteHero"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""ClamWin"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""CYREN"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""DrWebGateway"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Emsisoft"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""ESET"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Filseclab"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Fortinet"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""F-prot"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""F-secure"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""GFI"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Hauri"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Ikarus"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Jiangmin"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""K7"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-20T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Kaspersky"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Lavasoft"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""McAfee-Gateway"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Microsoft"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""NANO"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""nProtect"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Preventon"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""QuickHeal"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Sophos"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""STOPzilla"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-21T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""SUPERAntiSpyware"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Symantec"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Tencent"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""TotalDefense"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""TrendMicro"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-21T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""TrendMicroHouseCall"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-21T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""VirIT"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-20T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""VirusBlokAda"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-20T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Xvirus"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-23T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Zillya!"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-22T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0},""Zoner"":{""scan_result_i"":0,""threat_found"":"""",""def_time"":""2015-02-18T00:00:00Z"",""scan_time"":1.0}},""rescan_available"":true,""data_id"":""32fe182492834b6f88b1d95f6a14c886"",""scan_all_result_i"":0,""start_time"":""2015-02-23T13:10:55.549Z"",""total_time"":1.0,""total_avs"":43,""progress_percentage"":100,""in_queue"":0,""scan_all_result_a"":""Clean""},""file_info"":{""file_size"":0,""upload_timestamp"":""2015-02-23T00:40:41.029Z"",""md5"":""D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E"",""sha1"":""DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709"",""sha256"":""E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855"",""file_type_category"":""O"",""file_type_description"":""empty"",""file_type_extension"":""-"",""display_name"":""C:\\testy.xml""},""data_id"":""32fe182492834b6f88b1d95f6a14c886""}"
    Dim theobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj)
```

Comment: I need to iterate the json. Actually I need to get Virus Count on specific file. So from your code I think I'm unable to do it

Comment: No, you can. You can get to any value but it would be easier with @sloth's method. Or you could install Web Essentials for Visual Studio which adds a "paste json as classes" item to the Edit menu... though I'm not sure if it does VB.Net or just c#.

Comment: Can you see my answer, I have done it... but just need to verify that is there any other method that is better in term of performance,

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply guys. I have done it by following code snippet

```
 Dim jsonstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\json.txt")
    Dim jo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonstring)
    Dim scanDetail = jo("scan_results")("scan_details")
    Dim virusCount As Integer
    virusCount = 0
    For Each entry As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty In scanDetail
        entry.CreateReader()
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Name)
        For Each Val As Object In entry
            Dim abc = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(Val.ToString())
            Dim threatFound As String = abc("threat_found")

            Dim result As Integer = String.Compare(threatFound, "")
            If result = -1 Then
                virusCount = virusCount + 1
            End If



        Next
    Next

    If virusCount = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("No Virus")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Virus")
    End If
```

Comment: You don't need to (in fact you can't in VB) escape the backslashes in the path, so it should be `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\json.txt"`. (And you really shouldn't be logging in as Administrator, but that's for a different forum.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew Moron, I really do not know about it.

Comment: If you think it's correct, Please mark it right answer, because I'm unable to do it.

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours.